# How to use do() to replicate a result from plyr

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

Here's a piece of code in `plyr`. I split a dataframe dta by a grouping variable A, then apply a user defined function fn to each piece:

```
require(plyr)

dta <- data.frame(
  A=rep(LETTERS[1:7], each=1000),
  B=runif(7000)
  )

fn <- function(x){
  y <- x
  multiplier <- ifelse(
    x$A[1] %in% c("A", "D", "E"),
    3, 2
  )
  to_multiply <- y$B > 0.3
  y$B[to_multiply] <- y$B[to_multiply] *multiplier
  return(y)
}

dta_der <- ddply(dta, .(A), fn)
```

This works as I expect. (Note, the function itself doesn't matter. It's just an illustration.)

Now here's what I would expect would produce the same results using `dplyr`

```
require(dplyr)

dta <- data.frame(
  A=rep(LETTERS[1:7], each=1000), 
  B=runif(7000)
)

fn <- function(x){
  y <- x
  multiplier <- ifelse(
    x$A[1] %in% c("A", "D", "E"),
    3, 2
  )
  to_multiply <- y$B > 0.3
  y$B[to_multiply] <- y$B[to_multiply] *multiplier
  return(y)
}


dta %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  do(fn)
```

However, it produces `Error: Results are not data frames at positions: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` rather than the expected result.

Worse, with `plyr` I could do something like the following for `fn()`

```
fn2 <- function(x){
    browser()
    out <- NULL
}
```

This was immensely useful for being able to see the contents of each 'piece' passed to `fn`, in order to make sure it has the expected contents and structure, and to help develop the function accordingly. With `dplyr` this skeleton structure produces an error at the outset.

If, instead of using do, I pass the grouped tbl_df object to fn directly, no error is produced, but the pieces are not separated before being passed to fn. 
i.e. if I type `dim(x)` when `browser()` has halted fn2, I get `1000   2` in the `plyr` example, and `7000   2` in the `dplyr` example.

Is there any way of using `dplyr` for user-defined functions as I've been using `plyr`?
Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Please have a look at the `...` argument in `?do`: "You can use `.` to refer to the current group". Check the examples to get a feeling for how it is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this works....

you should check the results are as desired...

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(A) %>%
  do(fn(.))

#   A          B
#1  A 0.22276975
#2  A 0.01183619
#3  A 1.84315247
#4  A 0.19809142
#5  A 0.08114770
#6  A 1.48606944
#7  A 0.84864389
#8  A 0.60060566
#9  A 0.25362720
#10 A 1.68528202
```

by the way, if you want to not use `do` you can use the `%$%` pipe operator from `magrittr`

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(A) %$%
  fn(.)
```

Comment: Excellent. That's great.